# Hotkey for switching between tabs / window panes on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, in the Keyboard preferences window in System Preferences -> Keyboard, there's two tabs (or at least the equivalent for Windows) called Keyboard and Keyboard Shortcuts. Is there a hotkey to switch between these two ?

Comment: You can tab to the bar and use the arrow keys to select the tab you want (hit space or wait a second and it will swap to it). Other than that, I have found OSX terribly lacking in keyboard shortcut possibilities.

Comment: Better example, I'm in the Get Info window of a media file in iTunes, and I want to switch between 'Summary', 'Info', 'Video', 'Sorting', 'Options', 'Lyrics' and 'Artwork' with a keystroke. What do you call those things ? Because apparently there's a lot of ambiguity out there with the word 'Tabs' (I'm looking at you Lenwood)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer. You have to hit Command + [number of desired tab]. e.g. Command+1 takes you to the first 'tab', Command+2 the second, etc etc.

Comment: This is not always the case for every mac apps. Some apps support this behavior (e.g., Google Chrome and major browsers) but many other apps do not and they instead use these shortcut keys for UI layout options.

Answer (score 24):

Here are a couple of shortcuts that may be helpful.

- **Command + Tab** = switch between applications
- **Command + ~** = switch between windows of an application
- **CTRL + Tab** = move forward through tabs (in same window)
- **CTRL + Shift + Tab** = move backward through tabs (in same window)

Comment: See my example above in the comments under the original question. None of the keys mentioned in this answer work for switching between tabs in an OS window (Ctrl+(Shift+)Tab will work in Chrome tabs, but not OS window tabs)

Comment: Wow, that's a really good question. I'm not sure there's a keyboard shortcut to navigate between those tabs/windows/panes. Here's a list of [all OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343), I tried all of the ones that I could think of & came up with nothing. I tried a few other searches as well. If you find the answer please post back, I'm kinda curious about this now, too.

Comment: God, I should have checked this before.

Answer (score 17):

My personal favorite is to hold Command + Shift and then use `[` to flip left through tabs and `]` to flip right.

Comment: This is so much easier than CTRL + Tab and CTRL + Shift + Tab. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the cursor is not in a text area.

Comment: sure wish windows had this one

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox on macOS:

- <kbd>Ctrl + PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + PageDown</kbd> to switch tabs, and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> can be simulated with <kbd>Fn + Up</kbd>;
- <kbd>Command + 1</kbd> for first tab, etc; and
- <kbd>Command + 9</kbd> for last tab.

Answer (score 2):

Option (or Alt) ⌥ + Command (or Cmd) ⌘ + (left or right) arrow key

for changing tabs in chrome in MacOS.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This is not what the author of the question wanted to do, please read the question and existing answers carefully before answering a question. You find help on how to write good answers here https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer